# Обработчик нажатий клавиш под D

Tags: c, клавиатура, d

Как обрабатывать нажатия клавиш в языке D без использования win api(Нужно обеспечить работу под *nix). Есть доступ к API языка C.

Comment: Если речь идет об обработке нажатий клавиш в консоли, то тут никаких проблем, если же от окна, то нужно использовать какую-то из кроссплатформенных GUI-библиотек.

Comment: Да речь идет о консоли , не могу найти информацию

Comment: Скорее всего в стандартных библиотеках D такой функционал есть. Точно сказать не могу, у меня изучение D закончилось на 3 или 4 примере из книги Андрея Александреску. Пример отказался компилироваться в связи с тем, что в книге использовалась более старая версия стандартной библиотеки.

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего использовать кросс-платформенный фреймворк.

[Список](http://wiki.dlang.org/Libraries_and_Frameworks)

Выбор зависит от типа приложения.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность ).